# DoCmd.OpenForm error

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have another visual basic for excel question. I want to open a second form and pass an argument to it. It seems the best way to do this is calling DoCmd.OpenForm, but when I do this (either with or without argument), I get the following error "Run-time error '424' Object required" When I debug, it points at this line:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCommitTracker"
```

The same also happens with the following code:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCommitTracker", , , , , , getCaseID()
```

Any clues? Is this allowable in Excel or is it just for Access? I'm so confused!

Thanks,

1337Atreyu

Comment: `DoCmd` is Access, not Excel

Comment: Any suggestions for opening a new form and passing an argument to it in Excel? I have heard that global variables are a big no no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should open a second form and return to the original one when the second form is closed.

```
Me.Hide
UserForm2.Show
Me.Show
```

If you want to pass a value to the second form then see here for a few options: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/07/22/passing-arguments-to-a-userform/

Comment: Thanks Tim, that worked! I just passed the value as a tag. That worked out perfectly. It seemed kinda seedy/archaic somehow, so that's why I asked here to see if there were any other suggestions, but given the limitations of programming in excel, it's the best I can hope for. Thanks again!

Comment: The other appraoch of using a property defined on the second form is probably cleaner (though a bit more code), particularly if you find yourself needing to pass more than one parameter.